# Watson Assistance Solution Knowledge and Reasoning alpha REST API endpoints not working

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-assistant-solutions

I am not able to access the endpoint of Knowledge and Reasoning alpha feature of Watson Assistance Solution

Could someone help me to access the  WatsonAssistanceSolution  Knowledge component?

Comment: You probably need to create your own watson API key and use it?

Comment: As per my understanding in my case WAS has api_key as part of there tenant  so i should use that one only.                         
If Not    Can u please tell me how do i   create Watson  API key?

Answer (score 0):

The Knowledge and Reasoning API is an alpha service that was pulled out of the product. That would explain why you were not able to access it.